# ArrayList contains() is not using equals() method of a class

Tags: java, arraylist

I know there are so many answers for this question. But I have not found the solution.

```
class IpAddressRange
{
    InetAddress start;
    InetAddress end;

    public IpAddressRange(String start, String end) throws Exception
    {
        this.start = InetAddress.getByName(start);
        this.end = InetAddress.getByName(end);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object input)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside equals");
        long lv = IpAddressRange.ipToLong(start);
        long hv = IpAddressRange.ipToLong(end);
        if(input != null && input instanceof InetAddress)
        {
            long iv = IpAddressRange.ipToLong((InetAddress)input);
            if( iv >= lv && iv <= hv)
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return start.getHostAddress() + "-" + end.getHostAddress();
    }

    public static long ipToLong(InetAddress ip) {
        byte[] octets = ip.getAddress();
        long result = 0;
        for (byte octet : octets) {
            result <<= 8;
            result |= octet & 0xff;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I use `contains()` on the `ArrayList`, it is not using `equals()` method.

```
 ArrayList<IpAddressRange> allocatedList = new ArrayList<IpAddressRange>();
 allocatedList.add(new IpAddressRange("10.10.10.10","10.10.10.12"));
```

Below is the code that calls `contains()`:

```
 InetAddress inetAddress1 = InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.11");
 allocatedList.contains(inetAddress1);
```

But this `contains()` is not calling the `equals()` method of `IpAdressRange` class.

Comment: Looks like you have an issue in your `equals` implementation.

Comment: Is it calling the equals() method of the InetAddress?  That would accomplish the same thing, perhaps that's how it's implemented.

Comment: Now that I'm reviewing your code, you have `List<IpAddressRange>` and you're checking if it contains an `InetAddress`, so `InetAddress` is not equals to `IpAddressRange`, thus you should get an exception in your code. Or, you're posting the wrong code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, no. `ArrayList<T>.contains()` takes an `Object` not a `T`. Likewise `.equals( Object o )`. He just needs to implement it so `InetAddress.equals( Object o )` does the inverse check that `IpAddressRange.equals( Object o )` does.

Comment: @clcto I know it uses `Object#equals` behind the scenes. My question is *why* to have this odd design in the first place. Anyway, as noted by PaulHicks, the problem is that `InetAddress#equals` does not consider `IpAddressRange` in its implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your implementation for `equals()` does not agree with the implementation of `InetAddress`. The `equals()` method should be symmetric.

Take a look at the contract [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, `x.equals(x)`
>     should return true.
> - **It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values
>     x and y, `x.equals(y)` should return true if and only if `y.equals(x)`
>     returns true.**
> - It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x,
>     y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and `y.equals(z)` returns true,
>     then x.equals(z) should return true.
> - It is consistent: for any
>     non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of `x.equals(y)`
>     consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no
>     information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified. For
>     any non-null reference value x, `x.equals(null)` should return false.

The point is that you might be able to implement it like `anIpAddressRange.equals(anInetAddress)` returns `true`, but not the other way around, because you cannot edit the `equals()` method from `InetAddress`.

Comment: More important than making this `equals` implementation symmetric (which is in fact part of the contract) looks like code smell, since it would be better comparing `InetAddress` vs `InetAddress` or their subclasses (similar for `IpAddressRange`) instead of comparing two *unrelated* classes.